# I want the WPF Adorner to be drawn only on the desired area

Tags: wpf, xaml, adorner

If you obtain the AdornerLayer from the Canvas and draw the Adorner, it will still be drawn outside the Canvas.

```
                    if(newAdorner != null)
                    {
                        AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(_drawingCanvas).Add(newAdorner);
                        _adorners.Add(shapeItem.Uid, newAdorner);
                    }
```

```
        <!--<AdornerDecorator x:Name="DrawingAdorner">-->
            <Canvas x:Name="DrawingCanvas" Background="Transparent">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                        <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CanvasLButtonDownCmd}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                        <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CanvasLButtonUpCmd}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
                        <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CanvasMouseMoveCmd}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SizeChanged">
                        <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CanvasSizeChangedCmd}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Canvas>
        <!--</AdornerDecorator>-->
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ldhh.png)

How can I make the Adorner only appear within the Canvas area?

I try this.

```
        <AdornerDecorator x:Name="DrawingAdorner">
            <Canvas x:Name="DrawingCanvas" Background="Transparent">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                        <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CanvasLButtonDownCmd}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                        <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CanvasLButtonUpCmd}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
                        <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CanvasMouseMoveCmd}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SizeChanged">
                        <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CanvasSizeChangedCmd}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Canvas>
        </AdornerDecorator>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbI4k.png)

Answer (score 0):

The code works properly when modified as shown below.

```
        <AdornerDecorator>
            <Canvas x:Name="DrawingCanvas" Background="Transparent">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                        <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CanvasLButtonDownCmd}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                        <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CanvasLButtonUpCmd}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
                        <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CanvasMouseMoveCmd}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SizeChanged">
                        <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CanvasSizeChangedCmd}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>

                <ItemsControl x:Name="BoxItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Boxes}">
                </ItemsControl>
                <ItemsControl x:Name="EllipseItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Ellipses}">
                </ItemsControl>
            </Canvas>
        </AdornerDecorator>
```

Also I added ClipToBounds="True".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Pst2.png)